# Angular - detecting when two subscriptions have updated

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, promise, subscribe

In a component, in ngOnInit() I've got two subscriptions to a data service. I want to do some processing once both subscriptions have returned. Whats the best way to do this? I can just process at the end of each, this just seems a little inefficient and won't work for which ever subscription activates first,

Thanks,

Component.TS

```
ngOnInit()
{
  this.dataService.dataA().subscribe((dataAJSON) => 
 {
   this.dataA= dataAJSON
 }

 this.dataService.dataB().subscribe((dataBJSON) => 
 {
   this.dataB= dataBJSON
 }
```

DataService

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()

export class PMDataService
{
  constructor(public http : Http)
  {

  }

  dataA()
  {

    var dataA: any;
    var json;

    dataA= this.http.get("./assets/dataa.json")
      .map(res => res.json());

    return dataA
  }

  dataB()
  {

    var dataB: any;
    var json;

    dataB= this.http.get("./assets/datab.json")
      .map(res => res.json());

    return dataB
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [**Observable#forkJoin**](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html) function on the Observables. It emits the last value from each when all observables complete,

```
Observable.forkJoin(this.dataService.dataA(), this.dataService.dataB())
          .subscribe(val => /* val is an array */)
```

Answer (score 2):

The method used depends on how you want to receive the data:

You can use the [zip](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/zip.html) function.  Emits once when all have emitted once. So similar to `Promise.all` except not on completion.

```
Observable.zip(obs1, obs2).subscribe((val) => { ... });
```

You can use the [forkJoin](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-forkJoin) function.  Emits once when all have completed. So exactly like `Promise.all`.

```
Observable.forkJoin(obs1, obs2).subscribe((val) => { ... });
```

You can use the [merge](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/merge.html) function. Emits in order of emission so could be 1st then 2nd or 2nd then 1st:

```
obs1.merge(obs2).subscribe((val) => { ... });
```

You can use [concat](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/concat.html) function.  Emits in order 1st then 2nd regardless if 2nd emits first:

```
obs1.concat(obs2).subscribe((val) => { ... });
```

It's best practice to split these up into a couple lines for clarity.

```
const obs1 = Rx.Observable.of(1,2,3);
const obs2 = Rx.Observable.of(1,2,3);
const example = Observable.zip(obs1, obs2);
//const example = Observable.forkJoin(obs1, obs2);
//const example = obs1.merge(obs2);
//const example = obs1.concat(obs2);
example.subscribe(val => { ... });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the operator `Zip` or `CombineLatest` from rxjs.

See [ReactiveX operators](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators.html)

You could do something like this:

```
    Observable.zip(
        this.http.get("./assets/dataa.json"),
        this.http.get("./assets/dataa.json")
    .take(1)
    .map(values => [values[0].json(), values[1].json()])
    .subscribe(values => {
        // do something with my values
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could You can use [concat](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/concat.html) to combine the observables and return a single observable.

> Subscribe to observables in order as previous completes, emit values

changed service code

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/concat';

export class PMDataService
{
  data(){
    return this.dataA().concat(this.dataB());
  }
  // methods dataA and dataB are unchanged, some of the constructor
}
```

Component code

```
ngOnInit(){
  this.dataService.data().subscribe((dataJSON) => 
     {
       this.dataA= dataAJSON[0];
       this.dataB= dataAJSON[1];
     }
}
```