# Angular hide progressbar after data loads

Tags: angular

I am using FireStore Realtime Database in Angular.
I want to show a progressbar till the data loads from the database, and hide it after it loads.
This is my code:

```
  export class KavPatuachChatComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewChecked {

  messagesCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<MessageItem>;
  messages: Observable<MessageItem[]>;
  mAuthService: AuthService;
  constructor(public afs: AngularFirestore, public authService: AuthService) {
    this.mAuthService = authService;
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.getChatData();
}
  getChatData() {
    this.messagesCollection = this.afs.collection<MessageItem>('chat_messages', ref => ref.orderBy('DateTime'));
    this.messages = this.messagesCollection.valueChanges();
  }
```

How do I know when the data loads, in order to hide the progress bar then?

Answer (score 1):

```
this.afs.collection<MessageItem>('chat_messages', ref => {ref.orderBy('DateTime'); 
//code to hide progress bar
});
```

Comment: Yes, but How do I know when the data loads? Where is there an event or something like that to know that?

Comment: the above line that I mentioned is a call back function. It will be called once the data is loaded. alternatively, you can use `subscribe()` or other call back functions

Comment: Oh, but it gives me an error: Argument of type '(ref: CollectionReference) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'QueryFn'.
  Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'Query'

Comment: try this `this.messagesCollection.valueChanges().map(actions => {
//code goes here
});`

Comment: Could you please expand on your answer to prevent explaining the solution in the comments. thanks

Answer (score 1):

can't you use a *ngIf in the HTML component ? Use a boolean variable to control this before and after the load like this

in .ts

```
this.dataServiceProcessed = true \ false
```

In HTML

```
<div *ngIf="dataServiceProcessed">  
  Display something
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, but How do I know when the data loads? Where is there an event or something like that to know that?

Comment: I'm not sure if there's a more efficient way, You could create a data service and then subscribe like here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47338271/angular-detecting-when-two-subscriptions-have-updated, so after this.dataA= dataAJSON then set your boolean variable that controls the *ngIf